# What puzzles can I make out of origami?

Tags: puzzle-identification, mechanical-puzzles, three-dimensional

I recently made and solved a soma cube puzzle out of origami. What other puzzles can I make out of origami?

[image]

Comment: I'm sure if you try really hard you could make a Rubik's Cube. I tried one day but it didn't work very well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You listed the soma cube and the Rubik's cube, here are other ones. I didn't make them, I found them on a [French website](http://origami-art.org/blog/index.php?post/2014/10/11/Les-puzzles-en-origami):

- The four T puzzle:

  [image]

[image]

- [Francis Ow's Paradox](http://www.nickrobinson.info/clients/owrigami/show_diagram.php?diagram=paradox):

[image]

-The *Cubicus* (here's the [link to the diagram](https://www.flickr.com/photos/melisande-origami/sets/72157648394624541)):

[image]

-The Burr puzzle (diagram [here](https://origamiusa.org/files/Burr_Puzzle.pdf)):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can try and make a rubik's cube out of origami. It is possible but it is extremely difficult:

[image]

(No, I didn't make that)

You can see a made one [here](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=vdq-EDNkRpA) and watch how to make one [here](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=fvy3S9D_Vug). I haven't watched the full video as my connection isn't working but I think that will help.

Comment: Woah... That might be too ambitious for me. But thanks for sharing!