# Number Box Puzzle

Tags: tiling, seven-segment

[image]

All digits from 0-9 as shown are 1 in. thick and within 3x5 in.dimesion except number 1. The task is to put all the numbers inside the square box with smallest dimension nxn without overlapping of segments or flipping. Just rotation and segment insertion are allowed. How you can fit all digits from 0 to 9 inside the box?

Comment: Preliminary studies show this is too easy. Is there some other condition?

Comment: Yes,pse solvers are good ! (w/in an hour or less they can post a neat solution). maybe it is harder without actually making the cut outs for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I hinted in the comments, and since there's no [no-computers](/questions/tagged/no-computers) tag, there are a lot of solutions.

> Here's a packing into an 11×11 box with no flipping and all digits in only two orientations: [image] The total area of all pieces with holes filled in is 110 squares. The best-known packing of 110 unit squares into a square has the large square of side 11, so this is extremely likely to be optimal.

Comment: -That is the condition i'm trying to figure out ! " No Flipping"

Comment: $110 > 10^2$, so how could $11$ not be optimal?  Are you thinking of fractional side lengths?

Comment: @RobPratt Yes. I had thd four-T puzzle in [this answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/46040/75318) in mind when I wrote this up.

Comment: Oh, my impression was that you weren't supposed to move the 7 - is there some solution that works with the 7 in its starting position?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Yes, still a lot if the board is 12×12 as metrically implied by the diagram and the 7's top-left corner is at (4,4).